# capturing android soft keypad presses in javascript of html page in webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, android-webview, android-keypad

i am making a phonegap(v 1.3) android app. Bascically phonegap has a webview which loads an html page.
 I wanted to know if there was a way we can capture android soft keypad taps/clicks **in javascript of that page**, just like we could capture the key presses in javascript  of the keyboard if the html page were on a normal desktop browser. (using **keypress event**).

 I actually wanted to attach an handler to the event when a particular key is tapped on the soft keypad (enter key).

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap is not responsible for client side touch events. Its a bridge to give the client side additional functionality which the native application provides such as camera, accelerometer etc. If you are using jQuery mobile then have a look at the link.

> http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

```
  $("#myLink").bind('vclick',function(event){
        // do something
  });

   $("#myLink").bind('tap',function(event){
        // do other
  });
```

Comment: i know phonegap doesnt do that for now. i just wanted to know if there was something like keypress which we can use to know which key has been pressed on the soft keypad, in our js code. jquery mobile also doesnt have anything like that till now. :(

Comment: I think what you need is tap or vclick event.